# jquery ui date picker limit to Sundays

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have looked at some of the answers here to this type of question but could not get them to work how I needed them to. I need to have my jQuery UI datepicker only allow Sundays in the past to be selected. Is this possible to do?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***[It's not exactly your situation, but contains what you need to know to do what you need to do:](http://codeasp.net/blogs/raghav_khunger/microsoft-net/1088/jquery-datepicker-disable-specific-weekdays:)***

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"
        type="text/css" media="all" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/jquery-ui.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            // 0 = monday, 1 = tuesday, 2 = wednesday, 3 = thursday,
            // 4 = friday, 5 = saturday, 6 = sunday

            var daysToDisable = [2, 4, 5];

            $('#<%= txtDate.ClientID %>').datepicker({
                beforeShowDay: disableSpecificWeekDays
            });

            function disableSpecificWeekDays(date) {
                var day = date.getDay();
                for (i = 0; i < daysToDisable.length; i++) {
                    if ($.inArray(day, daysToDisable) != -1) {
                        return [false];
                    }
                }
                return [true];
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 15):

```
// Enable Sunday only
$("#datepickerID").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    minDate: 1,
    beforeShowDay: enableSUNDAYS
});
// Custom function to enable SUNDAY only in jquery calender
function enableSUNDAYS(date) {
    var day = date.getDay();
    return [(day == 0), ''];
}
```

Comment: Hi, this method is not working for me, I get the following error:
p.apply is not a function
[Break On This Error] A);t=(this._getFirstDayOfMonth(m,g)-h+...()==N.getTime()&&g==a.selectedMonth&& on line 531 of jquery-ui file Any help?