# datetime-local step not working on mobile

Tags: html, datetime

`<input type="datetime-local" step="1800"></input>`

The above line of code is not working on some mobiles. An attribute `step` is still 1 min on my phone.

tested phones: iPhone 6, iOS 10, with Safari and Chrome.

Any help?

Comment: Ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

You're correct. Same on Android. It seems the `step` attribute currently isn't supported on these mobile browsers. Meaning you may have to use a JavaScript-based datepicker for now (something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154916/jquery-ui-date-picker-limit-to-sundays)).

At the time of writing, [Mozilla mentions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date):

> You *should* be able to use the step attribute to vary the number of days jumped each time the date is incremented (e.g. to only make Saturdays selectable). However, this does not seem to be in any implementation at the time of writing.

Which technically isn't 100% correct as desktop browsers do seem to support it.

Answer (score 0):

### Let's explain at the begin how attribute `step` is working

The step attribute is a number that specifies the granularity that the value must adhere to, or the special value any, which is described below. Only values which are equal to the basis for stepping (min if specified, value otherwise, and an appropriate default value if neither of those is provided) are valid.

A string value of any means that no stepping is implied, and any value is allowed (barring other constraints, such as min and max).

> Note: When the data entered by the user doesn't adhere to the stepping
>   configuration, the user agent may round to the nearest valid value,
>   preferring numbers in the positive direction when there are two
>   equally close options.

For datetime-local inputs, the value of step is given in seconds, with a scaling factor of 1000 (since the underlying numeric value is in milliseconds). The default value of step is 60, indicating 60 seconds (or 1 minute, or 60,000 milliseconds).

At this time, it's unclear what a value of any means for step when used with datetime-local inputs. This will be updated as soon as that information is determined.

### Possible solution

To use this attribute we should specify also additional 2 attributes: `max` and `min`

**What is `max` attribute?**

The latest date and time to accept. If the value entered into the element is later than this timestamp, the element fails constraint validation. If the value of the max attribute isn't a valid string which follows the format yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm, then the element has no maximum value.

This value must specify a date string later than or equal to the one specified by the min attribute.

**What is `min` attribute?**

The earliest date and time to accept; timestamps earlier than this will cause the element to fail constraint validation. If the value of the min attribute isn't a valid string which follows the format yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm, then the element has no minimum value.

This value must specify a date string earlier than or equal to the one specified by the max attribute.

**Final code**

```
<input type="datetime-local" max="2020-06-20T20:06" min="2020-02-20T02:20" step="60"></input>
```

Comment: I interpreted the question as in "the step attribute is not respected in the datetime-picker". Ie the GUI still presents minute values that are not valid. If step is 1800 and min is "2020-11-25T00:00" then only the minute "00" and "30" should be available in the GUI. But as far as I can tell, most browsers ignore this when displaying the datepicker.