# Datepicker to select only sundays in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, visualforce

Below is my code- I need to restrict the user to select only sundays in the date picker, the rest days should be greyed out.So the date picker should only show sundays.

Please help me on this. Below code is working good, it defaults date to 4 week out from today and user can change it if possible.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
        var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
        var d = new Date();
        d.setDate( d.getDate()+28);
        var fromDateStart = new Date( d );
   
    
    var d = new Date();
        d.setDate( d.getDate()+29);
            var toDateStart = new Date( d );

        
        j$('.fromdatepickerctl').datepicker({
            startDate: getTodayDate()

                

        }).on("changeDate", function(e) {
            var fromDate = document.getElementById( e.target.id ).value;
            console.log('----> fromDate:  '+fromDate);
            var d = new Date( Date.parse(fromDate) );
            d = d.setDate( d.getDate()+28);
            j$('.todatepickerctl').datepicker('setDate', new Date(d) );
        });
   

        j$('.todatepickerctl').datepicker({
            startDate: getTodayDate()
        }).on("changeDate", function(e){
            var fromDateStr = j$(".fromdatepickerctl").val();
            var toDateStr = document.getElementById( e.target.id ).value;
            var parsedFromDate = new Date( Date.parse( fromDateStr ) );
            var parsedToDate = new Date( Date.parse(toDateStr ) );
            if( parsedFromDate > parsedToDate ){
                alert('To Date can not be less than From Date.');
                document.getElementById( e.target.id ).value = '';
                return false;
            }
        })
        
        j$('.fromdatepickerctl').datepicker('update', fromDateStart );
        j$('.todatepickerctl').datepicker('update', toDateStart );

    
        
        function getTodayDate(){
            var today = new Date();
            var dd = today.getDate();
            var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
            var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
            
            if(dd<10) {
                dd = '0'+dd
            } 
            
            if(mm<10) {
                mm = '0'+mm
            } 
            
            today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
            //document.write(today);
            return today;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: So if this code is working good, what do you need help with? What's the problem?

Comment: Please fix the snippet to actually work (it's missing jQuery now). Also: it's not completely clear what your issue is.

Comment: Which datepicker are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is the same issue that you are facing . 
This enables only Sunday in the datepicker .

[jquery ui date picker limit to Sundays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154916/jquery-ui-date-picker-limit-to-sundays)

```
 $(function(){


$("#thedate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    minDate: 1,
    beforeShowDay: enableSUNDAYS
});
// Custom function to enable SUNDAY only in jquery calender
function enableSUNDAYS(date) {
    var day = date.getDay();
    return [(day == 0), ''];
}

});
```

Comment: Doesn't appear OP is using jQueryUI datepicker